# Android AOA. Is FT312 RST pin pulling down == reconnecting USB cable?

Tags: android, android-usb, android-open-accessory

I am working on Android AOA project with FT312 chip. There is well known bug in Android where after Andoird app restarting there is a problem with inputstream data flow. Simple solution is to reconnect USB cable but that is not ok for me.

The question is:
If putting low FT312 RST pin gives me same result as unpluging USB cable? I wonder bacause charging will be still present. Question is if android USB port get full reset and problem with bug will be avoided.

Of course there is another solution: turning off +5V supply for FT312 and USB port for a while and turning on again. I am sure that will be work but that solution needs MOSFET power switch on board. Using RST pin of FT312 will be much more simple.

Thank You for reply

Regards

Comment: I had a project where I used RST button. Never seen any difference between cable (un)plug and RST button.
I am not quite sure about your chip, but as soon as bug is on Android side, there shouldn't be any difference for Android, hence it should solve it.

Comment: @Emil Finally I add Charging Manager IC between FT312D and USB connector to increase charging current. It has own EN pin which can cut off DM DP and +5V so that will be right solution to avoid Android bug.